# Struts 2 validation issues - no action mapped for util.js and validation.js

Tags: java, struts2

I am having a strange issues when i try to use xml based validation.

I have created a simple ActionClassName-validation.xml having validation on 2 fields for login.jsp page.

I have added the attribute validate = "true" in form tag.

Everytime i run the application and look at Tomcat logs i get following error.

There is no action mapped for namespace / and action util.js
There is no action mapped for namespace / and action validation.js

When i look at page source for Login.jsp the javascript section has 2 files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/HR/struts/xhtml/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/HR/struts/utils.js"></script>
```

It seems like these lines throw error when the page runs

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you defined your configuration in web.xml?

Comment: Hi Mohan thanks for you response. here is my web.xml  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

Change url pattern and update new filter.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```